# Blender with Three.js

Tags: three.js, blender

How can I use multiple materials for a 3D model in Blender and export it via the provided export-addon from three.js? I tried to do this, but I can only find THREE's basic materials "Lambert", "Phong" and "Basic", but I'd like to specify my own material. My 3D model in this case should be a house with wall- and glass-materials.

Answer (score 1):

You need this most likely:

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshFaceMaterial

You give it an array of materials, corresponding to your faces. The way the maxscript json exporter works is that it only exports multiple material ids (meshbasic, phong etc), if you assign a multi-mat material in max. Not sure what the equivalent of that is in blender.

Comment: So it just saves the material IDs but not the actual material to the file? And I should just create it in THREE? (assuming the THREE-specific json format is the same with Blender and maxscript)